# IE driver server unexpected close error working with selenium python

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working with python and selenium web-driver to test a web software. I have a simple script, which I have to put some wait on it while IE web-driver is up in order to do some actions with other test elements. After that wait seconds, first try to access web elements results in close error. An alert shows that the IE driver server has been stopped and I should close or restart the program.

There is also some logs in the system exception information as below:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: IEDriverServer.exe
  Application Version:  2.33.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    519d056f
  Fault Module Name:    IEDF41E.tmp
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   519d0564
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00015a90
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I got nothing from [the provided link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409) and also [this file](http://textuploader.com/kogn) which is `C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt`. I'm using Windows 7 AMD64 and python 2.7 with selenium 2.9. Any idea about this issue?

Comment: Step 1 is to upgrade your version of the IEDriver, to v2.42: http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.42/

Comment: @Arran, I edited the question; please check.

Comment: Check your initialization. 'webdriver.Chrome'?????

Comment: Yes @Arran, you are right, I removed it, but I should run my entire script. I'll let you know about the result.

Comment: Thanks @Arran. Your solution solved the problem; could you please add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Arran said, the problem was about updating IE driver serve; since I updated my driver exe file to the latest version from this [link](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.42/), there is no more exceptions.